# Скрыть ячейку TVirtualDrawTree

Tags: delphi

Вкратце:
Есть некое дерево, которое заполняется кучей данных и красиво отрисовывается. Нужно сделать группировку по признаку (см. скрин). Хочу сделать так: создал словарь, который заполняю key = признак, value = адрес ячейки, 1 ячейку показывать, остальные скрывать. И так для каждого признака. Собсна, споткнулся на скрывании. Ежу понятно, что надо работать с AfterCellPaint. Вопрос - как?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отставить со словарем. Словарь с этими параметрами есть. Можно определять рисовать или не рисовать в событии DrawNode. Вопрос. Как сделать рисование только по первому вхождению с данным значением параметра (параметр принимает в районе 10 значений, как определить с каким было вхождение, с каким - нет)?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте `array of Boolean` по количеству ячеек. Перед рисованием в ячейке `i` проверяете значение элемента `i` в этом массиве. Если `False`, рисуете ячейку и ставите там `True`. Если `True` - пропускаете ячейку. Когда фильтр меняется или нужно нарисовать по новой, выставляйте везде `False` в этом массиве.

Comment: Тогда может сделать массив по к-ву ключей, получать индекс ключа и в соответствующем элементе массива выставлять True?

Comment: Ну это вам виднее как лучше. Я вам задал направление для размышлений. =)